# Why are 2 arguments given to this python funktion?

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

```
from ev3dev.ev3 import *

from time import sleep


ml = LargeMotor('outB')
mr = LargeMotor('outC')
ts = TouchSensor()
cs = ColorSensor()
us = UltrasonicSensor()

cs.mode = 'COL-REFLECT'
us.mode = 'US-DIST-CM'


def motorenStop(stopaction):
    ml.stop(stop_action=stopaction)
    mr.stop(stop_action=stopaction)


def motorenRun(speed_sp, time_sp = None, stop_action = None):
    if time_sp is not None and stop_action is not None:
        ml.run_timed(time_sp=time_sp, speed_sp=speed_sp, stop_action=stop_action)
        mr.run_timed(time_sp=time_sp, speed_sp=speed_sp, stop_action=stop_action)
    else:
        ml.run_forever(speed_sp)
        mr.run_forever(speed_sp)




def drive():

    while 1==1:
        motorenRun(300)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/helloworld/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    drive()
  File "/home/robot/helloworld/drive.py", line 35, in drive
    motorenRun(300)
  File "/home/robot/helloworld/drive.py", line 26, in motorenRun
    ml.run_forever(speed_sp)
TypeError: run_forever() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I've tried to run my EV3 with python, now I got the issue, that 2 arguments are passed to a function. I searched for my issue, but I cant find any solution. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

[run_forever](https://ev3dev-lang.readthedocs.io/projects/python-ev3dev/en/stable/motors.html#ev3dev2.motor.Motor.run_forever) is a function that doesn't take any arguments by default. However, you'll notice that it has the argument `**kwargs`. This means you can pass in optional named parameters like so:

```
ml.run_forever(speed_sp=speed_sp)
```

Try see if that works.